# Python doesn't escape backslash in r'\' but it does in '\\'

Tags: python, escaping, backslash

For example, if I have

`myStr = r'D:\@Music\Classical\Scriabin'`

then

`print myStr[myStr.rfind('\\'):]`

works fine. I thought it would be equivalent to

`print myStr[myStr.rfind(r'\'):]`

but the latter expression raises an EOL exception.

Could anybody tell me why? The `r` should escape the single backslash or am I misunderstanding the whole thing altogether?

Comment: Refer the last part. r'\' not a valid string https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: Thx! I see. It's just a really odd exception.

Comment: Yes it is... I was baffled by question n i dearly wanted answer. But the explanation made sense. That odd no. of  \ will b treated as escape character n not string

Comment: Well, it says "Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character)." However, I think the backslash would *not* escape the quote because the backslash itself has been escaped by the `r`.

Comment: r'\' can be Interpreted as r escaping first ' and \ escaping second ' hence no valid string

Comment: Now i have confused myself.

Comment: Ha ha!! Well, as long as we get our jobs done, it's all good, right?

Comment: Yes :D it is of course true "it's easy to learn Python but not to use" ;)